# Tomcat 7 Tomcat 8 - initialization sql does not work

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

I have application installed on Tomcat, there is Oracle ojdbc driver and everything is working fine.

I need to run sql command when DB connect first.

I added this (**connectionInitSqls ="alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'"**) 
into the context.xml file in META-INF directory:

but still not working.

I tried it with Tomcat 7 and 8 versions and with different ojdbc drivers - ojdb6,7,8 - everything negative result.